# Filter a list of strings using math

Tags: filenames, wildcards, date

I have a directory with files listed like so:

```
abc201303130110.txt
abc201303140511.txt
abc201303150112.txt
```

As you can see, the filename contains a datetime stamp. I want to return all files with the value `201303140000` or higher in the filename.

I can get use grep to grab the datetime portion of the filename, but I don't know how to pipe through a filter that can do something like `X > 201303140000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `awk` is the GNU `awk`, you can simply use:

```
find . -type f | awk '{ match($0, /2013[0-9]+/,arr)}  arr[0] >= 201303140000 '
```

Comment: I see what you're doing here. You're pulling all dates within filenames, grabbing the ones within my criteria, then for each remaining date you run a grep. This seems highly inefficient as I need to process thousands of files/filenames often.

Comment: @Chaos  I have updated final solution

Comment: Does GNU awk support 64-bit integers everywhere, even if the local C compiler is an old one without `long long`?

Comment: @Gilles, awk uses doubles not integers. In this case though, you can force string comparison (`arr[0] >= "201303140000"`) to avoid that kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I changed the regex a little, but your solution works great!

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue! Perl's `-n` switch works a bit like `sed -n` and perl is more powerful in its matching and arithmetic.

```
dennis@lightning:/tmp/foo$ ls -1
abc201303130110.txt
abc201303140511.txt
abc201303150112.txt
dennis@lightning:/tmp/foo$ ls | perl -ne '$d=$_; $d =~ s/.*?(\d+).*/\1/s; print if $d >= 201303140000'
abc201303140511.txt
abc201303150112.txt
```

Comment: Why down vote this answer?

Comment: You can simplify that to `perl -ne 'print if /\d+/ && $& >= 201303140000'`

Comment: I tried this, and it works of course. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl abc<201303140000->.txt
```

Comment: Does zsh use 64-bit integers everywhere, even 32-bit systems whose C compiler is C89 and doesn't support `long long`?

Comment: This is really convenient, thanks for the suggestion.